# Prevent `less -R` from resetting colours across newlines

Tags: bash, colors, ansi-colors

How do I tell `less`, with `-R` or otherwise, not to reset colors across newlines(`\n`)? Here's an example of what I see:

```
$ echo -e '\033[31mThis is red.\nStill red.\n\033[0mBack now.' >> coltest
$ cat coltest
This is red. #Colour is red
Still red.   #Colour is red
Back now.    #Colour is the terminal's foreground colour.
$ less -RF coltest
This is red. #Colour is red
Still red.   #Colour is the terminal's foreground colour.
Back now.    #Colour is the terminal's foreground colour.
```

Why is the colour of `Still red.` reset to the terminal's foreground colour in the output of `less -RF`?

Comment: Think about what would happen if you scrolled to the end of the file and then worked backwards one line at a time. Note that `less` does this *without* even looking at previous lines.

Comment: @o11c Yes, I understand that applying attributes line-by-line is easier. However, note that there are indeed cases where `less` sees more than just one line - line numbers, for example. Of course, that does increase time needed for some `less` operations, but it is a tradeoff that `less` lets you choose. I was hoping for something along those lines here as well.

Comment: Same here with `docker-compose up` though `docker logs` shows properly.

Answer (score 2):

For some use cases `more` may be sufficient:

```
printf '\033[31mThis is red.\nStill red.\n\033[0mBack now.\n' >> coltest


more coltest
```

Comment: `less -r` comes with its own set of issues, as the `man` page tells you : "Warning: when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual appearance of the screen (since this depends on how  the  screen  responds  to each type of control character).  Thus, various display problems may result, such as long lines being split in the wrong place." In my case, `less -r` messes up colours two consecutive colour escape codes are more than a screenful apart.